# Why I get `Undefined variable` in Laravel 4.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass a variable from Controller to View :

**Controller**

```
class StaticDataController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function showIndex()
    {
        return View::make('index', array('test'=>'Hello World'));
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    {{ $test }}
@stop
```

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

And gets following error :

```
Undefined variable: test (View: /srv/www/htdocs/test/app/views/index.blade.php)
```

And here is my structure :

[image]

P.S:

*[routes.php]*

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `showIndex()` method was called, not an other?

Comment: to make that `showIndex()` was called. try to put `echo "show Index"; exit ;` before `return` and see the result.

Comment: @user41888 please paste your application Route

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy `routes.php` added to the question.

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov Yes, Look at `routes.php` file.

Comment: If you want call the `showIndex` method your route must look like this: `Route::get('/', 'StaticDataController@showIndex')`. In the current variant, with a closure, it is not point to the `showIndex` method, it just calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return View::make('index')->with('test'=>'Hello World');
```

Comment: i also recommend moving to laravel 5 , if you just starting learning.in laravel 5 what your trying to do works fine. but its written return view('index', array(...)); instead

Comment: try using another string instead of test , if it still doesnt work re-install, something is up with your app, or your development environment is not set correctly, or it can be that your browser is cached, or it can be that your storage directory is not being written do so fix permissions, try those and let me know.

Comment: It's `...->with('test', 'Hello World');` RTFM

Comment: @SarmenB. `View::make()` and `view()` under the hood is.... same. and your code is incorrect.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every
>   action in a controller. First, define the route using the
>   Route::controller method:

Your Route is incorrect and must be change to like with this line:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

or change to:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return View::make('index')->with('test', $test); 
});
```

and your controller :

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('index', array('test'=>'Hello World'));
    }

    public function postProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    public function anyLogin()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

then you can easily access to varibale in view such as :

```
{{test}}
```

Comment: @HamedKamrava my pasted code is correct and work file, if doesnt work your quastion is'nt correct

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Inside your controller:

```
$test = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
return View::make('index',compact('test'));
```

And inside your view:

```
@foreach($test as $value)
   <p>{{$value}}</p>
@endforeach
```